# Turn Laptop screen as Display for Android device with USB

Tags: android, usb, adb

trying to understand how things works,

From reading Android site, I know that utilize [Secondary display](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#SecondaryDisplays) & [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html)

1. But upon connecting Android device to laptop, how should I make it a USB appear to part of selection.
2. Is there anyway I can utilize browser like chrome to display the screen from Andriod device?

I notice Vysor able to do this, how is the big picture works?

thanks